# How to redirect FastAPI Documentation while running on Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, backend, fastapi

I need to redirect "**/swagger-ui.html**" to the documentation page.

I tried:

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/swagger-ui.html")
async def docs_redirect():
    response = RedirectResponse(url='/docs')
    return response
```

and

```
app = FastAPI(docs_url="/swagger-ui.html")

@app.get("/")
async def docs_redirect():
    response = RedirectResponse(url='/swagger-ui.html')
    return response
```

But, running the project directly (using uvicorn command) I works, but when I put it on a Docker container, it outputs this message on the browser, asking for the location, where nothing works as input:

> Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet
> registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is
> the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if
> the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the
> base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location
> manually:

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/backend
WORKDIR /usr/local/backend
EXPOSE 8080
ARG BUILD_ENV=dev 
ENV BUILD_ENV=$BUILD_ENV
COPY . /usr/local/backend
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--port", "8080"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code, it works for me when I use `docker-compose`:

```py
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def docs_redirect():
    return RedirectResponse(url='/docs')
```

Comment: ```from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse```

Comment: `from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse`

Comment: Adding  `include_in_schema=False` in the decorator will exclude this endpoint from showing in the Swagger UI

Answer (score 10):

To avoid showing the redirect in the docs page

```py
@app.get("/", include_in_schema=False)
async def docs_redirect():
    return RedirectResponse(url='/docs')
```

Documentation here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/path-operation-advanced-configuration/#exclude-from-openapi